# How to use Apache Geode type registry to write arrays of domain objects

Tags: gemfire, geode

I am working on a FIX repeating group where a quote request can have x legs. I have made a Leg class like this:

```
public class Leg : IPdxSerializable
{
  public string Side { get; set; }
  public decimal Size { get; set; }
  public string ValueDate { get; set; }

  public void ToData(IPdxWriter writer)
  {
    writer.WriteString("Side", Side);
    writer.WriteDouble("Size", Convert.ToDouble(Size));
    writer.WriteString("ValueDate", ValueDate);
  }

  public void FromData(IPdxReader reader)
  {
    Side = reader.readString("Side");
    Size = (decimal) reader.ReadDouble("Size");
    ValueDate = reader.readString("ValueDate");
  }

  public static IPdxSerializable CreateDeserializable()
  {
    return new Leg();
  }

  public Leg () { }
}
```

The legs for a quote request are written as an array of these `Leg` objects. In the quote request class there is a `Leg[]` declaration and `ToData FromData` implementation. The quote request object is built and `put` into a Geode region as a PDX Type, in which the array of legs is written by the PDX Writer as:

`writer.WriteObjectArray("Legs", Legs.ToList<object>());`

I have tried different types for the `List` of `Leg` as both PDX type and domain object type, but when I `get` the object in `GFSH` the leg array has given flavours of errors like:

`Could not create an instance of a class Leg (through reference chain: org.apache.geode.pdx.internal.PdxInstanceImpl[0]->org.apache.geode.pdx.internal.PdxInstanceImpl["object"])`

or

`Could not create an instance of a class Leg (through reference chain: java.util.Vector[0]->org.apache.geode.pdx.internal.PdxInstanceImpl["object"])`

I thought this was because the Geode server has not had a `Leg` object type registered in the server's `TypeRegistry`. Since Geode version 10 of the native client there is no longer a `Serializable.RegisterPdxType` which was used like this:

`Serializable.RegisterPdxType(Leg.CreateDeserializable);`

I have found the [TypeRegistry](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/dotnetdocs/a01138.html) class reference and on initializing the cache and regions also register the type into the cache:

`_cache.TypeRegistry.RegisterPdxType(Leg.CreateDeserializable);`

but still get the same error.

It's the same error if an array of Legs is written merely as an object

`writer.WriteObject("Legs", Legs);`

If I convert the `Leg` object into a `string[]` representation this is working fine with either `WriteStringArray` and `ReadStringArray` as a quote request where the `Legs` are an array of strings, but that has it's own problems, I want to use an array of Leg objects, preferably PDX wrapped. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

rupweb you can just use:

```cs
output.WriteObject(LEGS_KEY_, Legs);
```

and

```cs
Legs = (Leg[])input.ReadObject(LEGS_KEY_);
```

instead of WriteObjectArray/ReadObjectArray. Not sure what the limitations are on these. Still investigating.